# How can I add an item to an object dynamically?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this

```
  var idCliente = $scope.myClient.codigo;
  var nombreCliente = $scope.myClient.nombre;        
  var idProducto = $scope.myProduct.codigo;
  var nombreProducto = $scope.myProduct.nombre;        
  var cantidad = $scope.cantidad;          

  data = [];

  data.push({ idCliente, nombreCliente, idProducto, nombreProducto, cantidad });
```

but I don't know how to create a new one to append it to create an object list

Comment: Your object format is invalid

Comment: What does it mean 'new one'? Where should it be appended? Please clarify what do you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

I have some input tags to add some data to a list, and want to create a json object dinamically. for example, I want to add some product, name, type of product, quantity, etc.. and when I click on Add button, create the object but I want to add more than one, that's why I need to create something like this..

```
products = [
   {
     id: xxx, 
     name: xxxx, 
     type: xxx, 
     quantity: xxxx
   },
   {
     id: xxx, 
     name: xxxx, 
     type: xxx, 
     quantity: xxxx
   }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var idCliente = $scope.myClient.codigo;
  var nombreCliente = $scope.myClient.nombre;        
  var idProducto = $scope.myProduct.codigo;
  var nombreProducto = $scope.myProduct.nombre;        
  var cantidad = $scope.cantidad;          

  data = [];

  data.push({ idCliente: idCliente, nombreCliente: nombreCliente, idProducto: idProducto, nombreProducto: nombreProducto, cantidad: cantidad });
```

Comment: hi Praveen, that's work but create different object and I need it only in one to send and object of a objects